# Programatically add SEO properties in SharePoint 2013 public site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, seo

Need to add SEO properties to a SharePoint 2013 site programmatically. I know how to accomplish this in the UI but not through code. Any help would be great.

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the robots.txt exclusion you'd use the following sort of code. Imagine you also had a site called `topsecret`you wanted to exclude.

```
StringBuilder robots = new StringBuilder();
robots.AppendLine("User-agent: *");
robots.AppendLine("Disallow: /_layouts/");
robots.AppendLine("Disallow: /_vti_bin/");
robots.AppendLine("Disallow: /_catalogs/");
robots.AppendLine("Disallow: /toppsecret/");
web.SetProperty("xmlsitemaprobotstxtpropertyname", robots.ToString());
```

For the [Bing specific meta tag for web verification](http://blogtimenow.com/seo/meta-tag-verification-google-bing-alexa/)...

```
string newCustomMeta = "<meta name=\"msvalidate.01\" content=\"0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF\" />";
web.SetProperty("seoincludecustommetatagpropertyname", true.ToString());
web.SetProperty("seocustommetatagpropertyname", newCustomMeta);
```

For the [canonial URL tag](http://moz.com/blog/canonical-url-tag-the-most-important-advancement-in-seo-practices-since-sitemaps)...

```
web.SetProperty("seoenablecanonicallinkparameterspropertyname", true.ToString());
web.SetProperty("seocanonicallinkparameterlistpropertyname", "category");
web.Update();
```

For [MMS-based navigation SEO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163978.aspx)

```
TaxonomySession taxSession = new TaxonomySession(site, updateCache: true);
TermStore termStore = taxSession.DefaultSiteCollectionTermStore;
Group termGroup = termStore.GetSiteCollectionGroup(site, true);

// locate the navigation term set for the site collection (there can be only one)
foreach (TermSet termSet in termGroup.TermSets)
{
    NavigationTermSet navTermSet = NavigationTermSet.GetAsResolvedByWeb(termSet, site.RootWeb, StandardNavigationProviderNames.GlobalNavigationTaxonomyProvider);
    if (navTermSet.IsNavigationTermSet)
    {
        // determine which navigation nodes are associated with Welcome Page content types
        foreach (NavigationTerm navTerm in navTermSet.Terms)
        {
            string pageUrl = SPUtility.GetServerRelativeUrlFromPrefixedUrl(navTerm.TargetUrl.Value);
            SPListItem pageItem = web.GetListItem(pageUrl);
            if (pageItem.ContentType.Name == "Welcome Page")
            {
                // set the SEO properties on the Navigation Term (all will have same SEO tags)
                Term term = termSet.GetTerm(navTerm.Id);
                term.SetLocalCustomProperty("_Sys_Seo_PropBrowserTitle", Properties.Resources.SeoBrowserTitle);
                term.SetLocalCustomProperty("_Sys_Seo_PropDescription", Properties.Resources.SeoDescription);
                term.SetLocalCustomProperty("_Sys_Seo_PropKeywords", Properties.Resources.SeoKeywords);
                term.SetLocalCustomProperty("_Sys_Seo_PropSiteNoIndex", false.ToString());
            }
        }

        break;
    }
}

termStore.CommitAll();
web.Update();
```

Comment: Rob, will this MMS Navigation SEO also work if I'm using Structural Navigation?