# how to update SEO properties of sharepoint site page using powershell script?

Tags: 2013, powershell, seo

I want  to update SEO properties of page using powershell script.
is it possible by powershell or by applying any method?

Comment: See this question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93540/programatically-add-seo-properties-in-sharepoint-2013-public-site It is not PowerShell but you should be able to convert it easily enough.